in flutter/android using clipboard to pase image/webp as sticker to whatsapp inputfiled
I have stored WhatsApp sticker conform images with

mime type image/webp. So file ending is .webp
512x512 including 16px transparent border
file size is less than 100kb

I am loading the image in flutter like this:
Future<File?> readFileFromStorage(String fileName) async {
  Directory directory;
  try {
    directory = (await getPlatformSpecificApplicationDocumentsDirectory());
  } catch (e) {
    logger.e(e);
    return null;
  }

  final file = File('${directory.path}/$fileName');
  return file;
}

I am loading the image in an onPressed and saving it to clipboard
readFileFromStorage(widget.filePathWasticker).then((file) {
  if (file != null) {
  flutterImageClipboard.copyImageToClipboard(file);
}

In iOS I can paste a sticker with transparent background into:

any app
including WhatsApp. Here the Sticker modal of WhatsApp opens

In Android:

sticker with transparent background in Gmail, Signals, Telegram etc.
WhatsApp is opening the pasted clipboard as full scaled image with black background in the normal foto widget

I checked the mime type which is image/webp. I don't want to create a stickerpack but directly paste the sticker into the keyboard's inputfield so that the WhatsApp Sticker modal opens.
Any hint appreciated <3
